# Android avoid the Save contact to when calling the create new contact activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

could someone, please, give me a hand with the following problem?

I have an application which handles phone number and provides the user with the save new contact feature.
In order to save the new contact I've written the following code:

```
Intent addContactIntent = null;
addContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
addContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
addContactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phoneNumber);
```

This allows me to open the create contact activity, but before to reach this activity Android shows a dialog where I have to select wher I want to save the contact to.
In my scenario the dialog contains the following options:
Phone
Google
Microsoft Exchange

Since I need to always save the contact in the Phone I would like to go in the crate contact activity for the phone.

My question is: is there a way to avoid the "Save contact to" dialog? I think that it can be explicitly said via the Intent but I was not able to find out.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

[`ContactsContract.Intents.Insert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html) is a convenience class that has all the supported intent features for inserting a contact.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phoneNumber);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EXTRA_ACCOUNT, new Account(name, type));
```